# Call a ASPX from two different ASPX Pages

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have three ASPX Pages. The ASPX Page which get called from the two other Page is a Page where i can Upload files.

I call that Upload-Page from the other two Pages with JavaScript:

```
 function UploadFax_Click() {
             var grid = ISGetObject("WebGrid1");
             var curSelObj = grid.GetSelectedObject(); // get selected object
             var row = curSelObj.GetRowObject(); // get the WebGridRow object
             if (row.Type == "Record") {
                 var s_id = row.KeyValue
            }
            window.location = '../Admin/UploadFax.aspx?suppid=' + s_id;
         }
```

Then on the Upload-Page i get the QueryString:

```
 If Not IsPostBack And Len(Request.QueryString("suppid")) > 0 Then
        If Not Request.QueryString("suppid") Is Nothing Then
            Session("suppid") = Request.QueryString("suppid")
        End If
    End If
```

What i need is that if i call the Upload-Page from one of the two Pages the functions of the Upload-Page should be restricted. 
For Example: If i call the Upload-Page then Checkbox.Disabled = true and from the other page Checkbox should be enabled.

My idea was to send a second parameter from that page, then get the parameter with Request.QueryString and then use if/else to enable oder disable that checkbox.

Question is, is there another, better possibility to do that what i want? If yes how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `QueryString` may cause a security violation , Why not you use `Session` parameter,

when you Call it from the First Page then set

```
Session("IsCalled")="1"
```

in the second page load check

```
IF Not Session("IsCalled") Is Nothing AndAlso Session("IsCalled")="1" Then
   CheckBox1.Enabled=False
End If
```

and Vise Versa in the first page load.

Comment: i setted Session("IsCalled") = Request.Querystring("IsCalled"), because i need that Id wich i send as a parameter. Is that working? so i have to check in the if clause .......AndAlso Session("Iscalled") > 0 Then... Or is that wrong?

Comment: in your question your idea was to send a second parameter from that page, so `Session("IsCalled")` is to indicate which page was called lately and NOT to store ID, however you also can use another `Session` parameter to pass an ID

Answer (score 1):

You can check the `Request.UrlReferrer` and dance from it:

```
Dim restrictedAccess As Boolean = Not IsNothing(Request.UrlReferrer) AndAlso
        Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath.IndexOf("/Original.aspx", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0

Checkbox.Disabled = Not restrictedAccess
```

Comment: i never worked with Request.Url.Referrer before. How to use that?

Comment: @Paks Have you worked with `Request.Url`? It's of the same object type (`System.Uri`) providing information about the referrer's URI. MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx